# Dropbox redirect uri

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm accessing dropbox using OAuth 2.0 where it will gain an access token after succesfully authenticating a user. When I have successfully authenticating a user, I'm stuck at the success page where I have the authorization code. How do I redirect to my localhost and convert it to access token? I'm developing using php.

```
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("config.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();  
//echo $authorizeUrl;
header("Location:$authorizeUrl");

//$authCode = \trim(\readline("Enter the authorization code here: "));
$authCode = $_GET;
list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authcode);

print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
print_r($accountInfo);
```

Comment: Would you please share your code? It's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing how you're constructing the authorization URL.

Comment: I don't really know how to retrieve the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

You're using `WebAuthNoRedirect`, which doesn't do redirection back to your app. You need to use `WebAuth` (which *does* do the redirection). If you look at the `web-file-browser.php` example in the PHP SDK download, you'll see an example that looks like this:

```
function getWebAuth()
{
    list($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $userLocale) = getAppConfig();
    $redirectUri = getBaseUrl()."/dropbox-auth-finish";
    $csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
    return new dbx\WebAuth($appInfo, $clientIdentifier, $redirectUri, $csrfTokenStore, $userLocale);
}
```

I would start from that sample, as it's a complete end-to-end web app.